# How do I control an HTML5 audio player with AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, dom-events

I have a simple implementation in JavaScript that plays songs from a playlist continuously until it ends.
I have not been able to find which is the proper way to implement it in AngularJS. This exercise should address the desired features:

- Encapsulate player as a service
- Do I need to use directives to access the control?
- Catch the "end" event to start the new song

Here is an excerpt of the HTML file.

```
...
<div class="span4">
  <button class="btn btn-large btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="startPlaying();">Start Playing</button>
</div>
...
<div class="span6">
  <h4 id="NowPlayingID">Now Playing: </h4>
  <audio id="AudioPlayerID" controls="controls">
  </audio>
</div>
...

<!-- OLD JavaScript code -->
<script type="text/javascript">
  function playNextSong(player) {
    if (playlist.currentSongIX >= playlist.songs.length) 
        return;
    $('#NowPlayingID').text('Now Playing: ' + playlist.songs[playlist.currentSongIX].name);
    player.src = playlist.songs[playlist.currentSongIX].path;
    player.play();
    playlist.currentSongIX++;
  }
  function startPlaying() {
    var player = document.getElementById("AudioPlayerID");
    player.addEventListener('ended', function() {
        playNextSong(player);
        }, false);
    playNextSong(player);
  };
</script>
```

---

The following code is work in progress and incomplete:

```
app.controller('PlayCtrl', function($scope, $routeParams, Playlist, $log, $document) {
  $scope.playlist = Playlist.get({playlistID:$routeParams.playlistID});
  var player = ????? ("AudioPlayerID");
  $scope.startPlaying = function () {
      angular.forEach($scope.playlist.songs, function(song) {
  $log.log("Playing: " + song.name);
  player.src = song.path;
  player.play();
      });
  };
});
```

...

My questions are:

1. Which is the proper way to access the audio player?
2. Do I need to use directives?
3. How do I catch the 'end' event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've build a html player backended by flash to play music, so build my own event flow to to the operations, but I think that the best way is to write an directive to do that. In this case you can re-use the directive if you need to and it works very well.

If you have the player object into your directive, you can catch all events normally.

Take a look on this website: [Angular Tunes](http://angular.github.io/peepcode-tunes/public/) and check out the sources to see what he does. It's the same as you trying to do.

I hope it helps.

Comment: The Angular Tunes site did eventually lead to me to some good information and got it working embedding the code in the controller and defining the audioControl in the services portion. Next step is to figure out how to make use of the directive.

Comment: If you need some help just send me a plunker or jsfiddle =)

Comment: This does not answer the question